# UI Issues - Swipe to delete RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, delete-row

The issues I faced which is recycler view would not able to update UI correctly while user deleting item. The data have removed but it will remain a empty row on the UI. Please save me from the dark.Thanks.

Before

[image]

After deleted

[image]

Here is the code

```html
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {


                final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

                listData.remove(position);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);


            }
        };

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
```

Comment: Try this `listData.remove(position);
                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @NileshRathod  Same , I tried 3 days

Comment: the adapter is in the same activity or particular class?

Comment: Do this ,may this will work for you.  ***listData.remove(position);  
notifyItemRemoved(position);***